# How do I fix the operation switch statement

Tags: java, enums, switch-statement

In this class, called AClass, I tried making a switch statement that would use the operator inputted between two values.

```
public interface Operation {
  public enum Operator {Add, Sub, Mult, Div, Rem}
}


import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class AClass<I> implements Operation {

    AClass <Integer> leftoperand = new AClass <Integer>();
    AClass <Operator> operation = new AClass <Operator>();
    AClass <Integer> rightoperand = new AClass <Integer>(); 

  public Integer value (SClass sc) {
    switch (operation) {
        case Add:
            return leftoperand.value(sc) + rightoperand.value(sc);
        case Sub:
            return leftoperand.value(sc) - rightoperand.value(sc);
        case Mult:
            return leftoperand.value(sc) * rightoperand.value(sc);
        case Div:
            return leftoperand.value(sc) / rightoperand.value(sc);
        case Rem:
            return leftoperand.value(sc) % rightoperand.value(sc);
    }
  }

  public String toString() {
   return "(" + leftoperand + "," + operation + "," + rightoperand + ")";
  }
}
Error: incompatible types: AClass<AClass.Operator> cannot be converted to int

Error: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable Add
  location: class AClass<I>

Error: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable Sub
  location: class AClass<I>

Error: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable Mult
  location: class AClass<I>

Error: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable Div
  location: class AClass<I>

Error: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable Rem
  location: class AClass<I>
```

and I received some errors, starting with the switch (operation) line. How do I go about fixing this?
Also, could I just insert the enum Operator inside of AClass instead of using an interface?

Comment: You start by changing field `operation` to be a `Operator`, not an `AClass <Operator>`, and rename the field to `operator`.

Answer (score 0):

Java switch statements don't support all the classes.
From java doc,
Unlike if-then and if-then-else statements, the switch statement can have a number of possible execution paths. A switch works with the byte, short, char, and int primitive data types. It also works with enumerated types (discussed in Enum Types), the String class, and a few special classes that wrap certain primitive types: Character, Byte, Short, and Integer (discussed in Numbers and Strings).

```
AClass <Operator> operation = new AClass <Operator>(); // will not work
Operator operation = Operator.ADD; // will work since operator is an enum;
```

Comment: So I must use the .ADD function instead of the <Operator> element? I can keep my switch statement then?

Comment: Just to clarify ADD is not a function its an enum, yes you can use the ADD enum and keep the switch statement.